# Why $\liminf \limits_{n \to \infty} (\int_X g_n(x) d\mu - \int_X f_n(x) d\mu) = \int_X g d\mu - \limsup \limits_{n \to \infty} \int_X f_n(x) d\mu$?

Tags: real-analysis

Given $f_n \to f$, $g_n \to g$, and $\int_X g_n d\mu \to \int_X g d\mu$, why we can get this:

$$\liminf \limits_{n \to \infty} \left ( \int_X g_n(x) d\mu - \int_X f_n(x) d\mu \right ) =
\int_X g d\mu - \limsup \limits_{n \to \infty} \int_X f_n(x) d\mu$$

The above line is a step that I need to use to prove The Generalized Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem. I need a proof for the above line.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have any ideas of your own? Once we have a better idea of exactly where you're struggling, we can help you better ^_^

Comment: Do you know the following fact about $\liminf$: if $a_n\to a$ then $\liminf(a_n+b_n)=a+\liminf b_n$?

Comment: Note that $-\sup(a_n)=\inf(-a_n)$

Comment: @operatorerror Yes, I know this fact and its proof. And this fact is also used in the proof of The Generalized Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem.

Comment: @operatorerror Aha, now I understand. Thanks!

Comment: @Mariana No problem. Good luck